# how can I solve ODE by separable method $y''-2y'=x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know the method which uses the characteristics equation for homogeneous equation to find the complementary solution and after that we will find the particular solution, but I ask if there is a possibility of finding the general solution by separable method. any help, thanks

Comment: Separation of variables can only be used for first order ODEs

Comment: @alex Why for first order??

Comment: Separation of variables uses the fact that y' = f(x)g(y) (i.e. the RHS can be separated) which makes direct integration possible. in a second order ODE you usually have a second order derivative and a first order derivative which makes this impossible.
it's a different story if y' = 0.

Comment: You can change this to a first order linear differential equation using y'=vx. Find integrating factor and solve for v. Then from v, you find y.

Comment: Guess I could have just used y'=v instead. :p

Comment: Separation of variables? What for? Note instead that $$y''-2y'-x^3=\left(y'-2y-\tfrac14x^4\right)'$$ hence the equation to be solved is $$y'-2y=\tfrac14x^4+c.$$ Likewise, $$(e^{-2x}y)'=e^{-2x}(y'-2y)$$ hence the equation to be solved is $$(e^{-2x}y)'=e^{-2x}\left(\tfrac14x^4+c\right),$$ that is $$y=e^{2x}\left(c'+\int_0^xe^{-2t}\left(\tfrac14t^4+c\right)dt\right),$$ and we seem to be very close to a full solution, don't we?

Answer (score 2):

Notice, variable separable method is applicable for first order D.E. But for a second order D.E., first we find complementary solution & then particular solution as follows

let $y'=Dy$, then  $(D^2-2D)y=x^3$

For complementary function (C.F.), $$D^2-2D=0\implies D=0, 2$$
$$C.F.=A+Be^{2x}$$
The particular integral is given as $$P.I.=\frac{x^3}{D^2-2D}=-\frac{1}{2D(1-\frac{D}{2})}x^3=-\frac{1}{2D}\left(1-\frac{D}{2}\right)^{-1}x^3$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2D}\left(1+\frac{D}{2}\right)x^3$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2D}\left(x^3+\frac{3x^2}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^4}{4}+x^3\right)=-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^3}{2}$$
hence, the general solution is $$y=C.F.+P.I.$$
$$y=A+Be^{2x}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^3}{2}$$

Comment: (+1)this is nice solution but it is not what I need

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, by "separable method", E.H.E does not mean "separation of variables" but rather separating the equation into the "homogeneous part" and "non-homogeneous part".  The "associated homogeneous equation" is y''- 2y;= 0.  Its characteristic equation is $r^2- 2r= r(r- 2)= 0$ so r= 2 and r= 0.  That means that the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $C_1e^{2x}+ C_2e^{0x}= C_1e^{2x}+ C_2$.

Normally, given a "non-homogeneous part" $x^3$, we would look for a solution of the form $Ax^3+ Bx^2+ Cx+ D$.  However, since the constant $C_2$ is a solution to the associated homogeneous equation, we need to try $y= Ax^4+ Bx^3+ Cx^2+ Dx$.  Then $y'= 4Ax^3+ 3Bx^2+ 2Cx+ D$ and $y'=12Ax^2+ 6Bx+ 2C$.

So $y''- 2y'= (4Ax^3+ 3Bx^2+ 2Cx+ D)- 2(12Ax^2+ 6Bx+ 2C)= 4Ax^3+ (3G+ 24A)x^2+ (2C+ 6B)x+ (D- 2C)= x^3$

Since these are to be equal for all x, corresponding coeffcients must be equal so we have 4A= 1, 3G+ 24A= 0, 2C+ 6B= 0, D- 2C= 0.  Solve those equations for A, B, C, and D.

Comment: I think this is not what I need

Comment: @E.H.E I don't quite understand. This is exactly what you would do to solve a second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation. You find the general solution, ie $Ly=0$, and then you find the particular solution using the method of undetermined coefficients. Then you add the general solution and the particular solution to get the total general solution for the ODE.

Comment: @E.H.E If you mean you want to try the method of reduction or order, that would still make this an integrating factors problem....it's just not separable.

Comment: @Simon, In fact, my friend challenged me to solve it by separable method.

Comment: @E.H.E Honestly, I'm not seeing how this can be solved via separable...

Comment: @E.H.E Apologies, but I think we were using different definitions of separable. If you're talking about solving it by separating it and integrating it, then you can't do it for second order ODEs. If you mean separable in the sense that you move all the y's to the left side and all the x's to the right side, then this is already, in a sense, separated, and you would use this solution to solve it.

Comment: @Simon I mean by separating it and integrating it